# specifying a custom return Url in Auth0 logout produces an error

Tags: asp.net-core-mvc, auth0

I have the following as defined in asp.net core Auth0 guide:

```
if (user == null)
            {
                await HttpContext.SignOutAsync("Auth0", new AuthenticationProperties
                {
                    RedirectUri = Url.Action("Error", "Account")
                });
                await HttpContext.SignOutAsync(CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme);
            }
```

I would like the user to be redirected to /Account/Error page, but I get the following error:

> The "returnTo" querystring parameter
>   "http://localhost:60856/Account/Error" is not defined as a valid URL
>   in "Allowed Logout URLs". To add a new URL, please do it here:
>   https://manage.auth0.com/#/applications/C3hMD9L4om3hhlddrZbIFgvU2CnDcXcf/settings

But the problem is that I have already added exactly that url in my tenant settings allowed urls textbox. Is this a problem on auth0 end?

Answer (score 0):

How did you redirect from there? I would recommend capturing a HAR file and inspecting where it goes. At a glance you may be having issues with your RedirectURI if you have your dashboard setup appropriately.

- https://auth0.com/docs/users/guides/redirect-users-after-login